# Images not working in wordpress installed in a subdomain/subdirectory

Tags: wordpress

I installed a copy of another wordpress installation of a client in a subdomain. All seems to work fine but images don't. I'm using videos as background and they are working perfect. If I take a look inside the media menu the images are not visible (you can only see an X for every image), but if you manually take the link of every image all the links works fine and images are accesible.

I suspect that issue is related with any of the functions that process images. Maybe some kind of error related with the subdomain which obviously have a dot in the domain name.

¿Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you uploaded the images of the client's WordPress installation via FTP.

As far as I know WordPress Media Library cannot “see” images that are not uploaded through the Media Library uploader. The Media Library uploader (aside from uploading your media) creates necessary references within WordPress which you don't have when uploading media via ftp.

This is a common WordPress flaw. There are plugins which might solve your problem by creating the necessary references after such a ftp upload, e.g. [Add From Server](https://wordpress.org/plugins/add-from-server/).